# Como pegar o data-value do data-list

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho uma `data-list` para os nome de professores, cujos valores (values) são os nomes dos mesmos. De forma padrão, no submit o `input` captura os dados contidos em `value`. O que gera um problema, já que meu banco de dados espera um valor númerico.

Quando mudo os valores dos `option` para númerico (1 para o nome 1, 2 para nome 2 e etc.), gera outro problema (dessa vez estético): o usuário seleciona um professor, e no campo de seleção não aparece mais o nome, e sim o valor do `value`.

```
                <datalist id="teachers">
                    <select>
                        <option data-value="1" value="Nome 1">Nome 1</option>
                        <option data-value="2" value="Nome 1">Nome 2</option>
                    </select>
                </datalist>
```

**Resumo:** Quero que na barrinha de seleção apareça o nome do professor selecionado, e que seja enviado para o `input` um valor númerico.

O `data-value` do código é de uma dica que encontrei [aqui no stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214704/how-to-get-data-value-in-data-list), mas não funcionou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você não está fazendo o tratamento do formulário com `javascript` o que será enviado no valor de seu campo `<input>` será o valor da opção (isso é padrão) como demonstrado no código abaixo (simples demonstração):

```js
let input = document.getElementById('x')

input.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
    if ( input.value !== '' ) {
        alert(this.value)
    }
}, false)
```

```html
<datalist id="teachers">
    <select>
        <option data-value="1" value="Nome 1">Nome 1</option>
        <option data-value="2" value="Nome 2">Nome 2</option>
    </select>
</datalist>

<input id="x" type="text" list="teachers">
```

Se você fizer um tratamento usando `javascript` podes pegar o valor do `<input>` e buscar com `querySelector()` um elemento `<option>` que tenha no atributo `value=""` um valor igual e extrair/recuperar o conteúdo de seu atributo `data-value` e reatribuir este valor (vindo do `option`) ao `<input>`, exemplo:

```js
let input = document.getElementById('x')

input.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
    let selector = document.querySelector('option[value="'+this.value+'"]')
    if ( selector ) {
        input.setAttribute('value', selector.getAttribute('data-value'))
        console.log(input)
    }
}, false)
```

```html
<datalist id="teachers">
    <select>
        <option data-value="1" value="Nome 1">Nome 1</option>
        <option data-value="2" value="Nome 2">Nome 2</option>
    </select>
</datalist>

<input id="x" type="text" list="teachers">
```

---

PS: os valores passados por um formulário (x-www-form-urlencoded) são `{String}` normalmente funções de comparação (usadas no servidor) já lêem a `{String}` como se representassem números exemplo:

```
"10" > 5  // verdadeiro
"10" > 15 // falso
```

Contudo, se você deseja salvar no banco de dados um valor "numérico" o ideal seria converter esta `{String}` numérica para um número de fato:

```
// em PHP
$string_number = "10";
$number = (int) $string_number;
// test
echo(gettype($string_number).' - '.gettype($number));
// output: string - integer

// em JavaScript (Node)
let stringNumber = "10",
    number = Number(stringNumber)

// test
console.log(typeof stringNumber +' - '+ typeof number)
// output: string - number
```

---

**edição:**

Ok, o segundo exemplo modifica o valor do "nó" no`DOM` mas não o valor do `<input>` que esta em memória ... uma abordagem não muito diferente deste exemplo (o segundo) usa um observador de evento `submit` para o formulário.

Observando o evento `submit` é possível substituir o valor do `<input>` sem que haja uma mudança perceptível ao usuário (uma vez que o valor "visível" será mudado do nome para um "número").

```js
let input = document.getElementById('x')

input.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
    let selector = document.querySelector('option[value="'+this.value+'"]')
    if ( selector ) {
        this.form.addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
            input.value = selector.getAttribute('data-value')
        }, false)
    }
}, false)
```

```html
<datalist id="teachers">
    <select>
        <option data-value="1" value="Nome 1">Nome 1</option>
        <option data-value="2" value="Nome 2">Nome 2</option>
    </select>
</datalist>

<form method="post" action="/?">
    <input id="x" name="teacher" type="text" list="teachers">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

A recomendação (caso queira salvar um número no banco de dados) continua a mesma.

Testado em:

- **Node**: versão 8.9.4
- **PHP**: versão 7.0

Comment: Se existe possibilidade de "conflito" com outros elementos `<option>` na página, o ideal seria passar na "query" de consulta o `id` do `<datalist>` e percorrer seus elementos na busca de uma opção que atenda a consulta exigida (um `value` igual ao valor do `<input>`)

Comment: Quando envio o valor para o formulário o valor enviado continua sendo o `value` que está em `option`. E aí dá erro porque o banco de dados espera um número e recebe uma `{String}` como, por exemlo, {Nome 1}. @LauroMoraes

Comment: @WellingtonAlbertoni você marcou a resposta pq conseguiu resolver? Caso não, qual é sua linguagem no servidor?

Comment: Uso PHP e a propósito, o action do form está para a mesma página `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"`

Comment: Quando escolho uma opção da lista, no console aparece `<input [...] value="1" type="text">`, ele recebe em `value` o valor que está em `data-value` mas na hora de enviar ele não envia ESSE `value`, e sim o da lista.
`

Comment: Se quiser dar uma olhada, o código da página está [aqui](https://github.com/wellingtonalbertoni/site/blob/master/register_feedback.php), o `input` em questão está na linha `47`, o javascript na linha `74`.

Comment: Ok, fiz uma edição...localmente parece ter resolvido o problema do segundo exemplo. Teste ai e repasse um feedback para que possamos saber se resolveu a questão

Comment: Perfeito! Resolvido, muito obrigado!!!!!